# What could this blue ring on my ceiling be and what are my options?

Tags: ceiling, mold, water-damage

Today I noticed that there was this brightish blue ring emanating from a crack from my ceiling. I hadn't noticed this before.

Earlier this week my cat broke a full glass of water directly above it. I hadn't noticed the broken glass until I went to bed that night, so the water could have been sitting on the ground for about 12 hours.

What could it be? Mold? Staining?

What are some of the options that I have to fix the crack / stain / mold ?

[image: Here's an image of the portion of the ceiling in question.]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a water stain. Since you know the cause, just get matching ceiling paint and paint over it,  or repaint the whole ceiling if you can't get the color matched to your satisfaction. Or ignore it until you're ready to repaint.